# Google IOT - device subscribe to something else than /devices/XXXX/config

Tags: iot, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-iot

I am trying Google IOT and Google PubSub.
I am sending MQTT messages from device to a pubsub queue on which I have subribed (with something I will call "the server").
From the google cloud console, I update device setting and I get the setting message in device.

Everything in google tutorial work fine but I wonder if it is possible to set up a messaging it the other way : i.e. "the server" sending message to a pubsub queue subscribed by the device using MQTT.

The schema at the end of [this page](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/concepts/overview) make me think that only the "config" mqtt queue (/devices/XXXX/config) can be used that way.

What I need is a 1to1 communication from "the server" to "the device" and I'm afraid that the only way is using the config

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert on Google IoT, but few days ago I got the same doubts about it. Apparently, although we can publish to `/events`, `/config` and `/state` topics, using MQTT protocol, only topic `/config` and, maybe, `/state` can work through subscriptions with the same protocol.

The conclusion I got, after reading many times the documentation, that is not so clear, and asking some questions here at stackoverflow is: you can not use MQTT to subscribe to any topic in order to receive those data sent to `/events` topic.

To accomplish this, you have to create a Pub/Sub topic associating it to your device:

1. On [Google Cloud IoT Core Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iot/), click on your registry ID;
2. Create a standard telemetry topic;
3. After topic created, click on the topic to see its details;
4. Its details will open on [Google Cloud Pub/Sub panel](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/);
5. In this panel, you can create a subscription to the created topic, by clicking on the "create subscription button".

Now that you have a "google cloud pub/sub topic" linked to "google cloud iot core `/events` telemetry MQTT topic" and a respective subscription, you can use the [google pub/sub library](http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pubsub/index.html) to receive notifications through created subscription when data are sent to `/events` topic.

Maybe the following link can also help:
https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices#creating_a_device_registry_with_multiple_pubsub_topics

I hope this can help you. If I made any mistake in my answer, may someone edit it with some improvement or correction.

Answer (score 0):

Today I got same issues. Seems you cannot get data by subscribe with MQTT. You need to create a pub/sub topic in Goolge iot pub.sub